Selenium::Chrome gets "unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist"
#!/usr/bin/perl -w0

use Selenium::Chrome;

$|++;
print "PATH: $ENV{PATH}\n\n";

my $chrome = Selenium::Chrome->new(
     browser_name       => 'chrome',
     extra_capabilities => {
       chromeOptions    => {
         args           => [ 'window-size=1920,1080',
                             'headless',
                             'no-sandbox',
                             'disable-dev-shm-usage',
                           ]}});

$chrome->get('http://www.google.com');


It prints $PATH as follows:
PATH: /root/.local/bin:/root/bin:/home/admin/.local/bin:/home/admin/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/admin/.selenium

But it can't proceed with the code due to the following error:
Could not create new session: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)


The google-chrome binary is in /usr/bin/:
# /usr/bin/google-chrome --version
Google Chrome 124.0.6367.118 


The chromedriver is in /home/admin/.selenium/:
# /home/admin/.selenium/chromedriver --version
ChromeDriver 114.0.5735.90 (386bc09e8f4f2e025eddae123f36f6263096ae49-refs/branch-heads/5735@{#1052})


Furthermore (probably irrelevant):
# java -jar /home/admin/.selenium/selenium-server-standalone.jar --version
Selenium server version: 3.9.1, revision: 63f7b50


I have no idea what gets wrong, and why I am experiencing the error

Could not create new session: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally


Did this ever work on your system (perl+selenium+chrome) or is it a new setup?

@zdim - I'm moving my stuff from old server to a new one. I had this working on the old one for years.

How about the first guess: move your chromedriver to a more standard bin directory?  Like /bin or /usr/bin. What distro is this?  On a RHEL based distro there is a chromedriver rpm, and it installs it in /usr/bin.  (I see that ~/.selenium/` is in your path, but still.)

As for simple guesses, I'd also reduce the desired window size (or just leave it out altogether).  But -- this is apparently a known, big issue.  Search for devtoolsactiveport file doesn't exist, from your error message.  There are Stackoverflow posts with 1/2 million views

@zdim - unfortunately, window-size=800,600 made no difference
